# No links work, page anchors or external, and I get no errors in Firebug

Tags: jquery-mobile, responsive-design

I apologize if this is grade schools stuff but I'm brand new to this. I'm trying to make a responsive site and using jquery mobile and I finally got one page to LOOK ok on desktop and mobile, but none of the links work (page anchors OR external links). I've searched all kinds of things about this and have never posted a question before but I've run out of things to search for.

The page is located at: http://www.piasc.org/raise/jQ/competitions.html

Can anyone see what's wrong with the links? P.s. I don't know anything about javascript and would prefer not to have to resort to that. Links used to be simple in html, what happened?

Edit: Ok, now that's just bizarre...I corrected the external links and now the URL changes but the new page loads BELOW the current one in Firefox and Safari, but works fine on my iPhone.

Comment: Firebug console clearly shows that it can't find the resource. Like, I clicked Graphics Art School and it threw a 404 error.

Comment: oh, yes, you are totally right, the external links aren't yet linked to anything. It's the page anchors I'm very concerned about right now.... and I can't understand why my firebug wont tell me anyhting.

Comment: Do you want to scroll to div with id as in `href="#top"`?

Comment: yes! That's the idea...

Answer (score 1):

If you want to scroll to a target div within active page, you should add `data-ajax="false"` to anchor. This will inform jQuery Mobile framework that you're not navigating to hash page.

```
<a href="#top" data-ajax="false">TOP</a>
```

Comment: Thank you! I think you're right so I've decided to axe the jQuery mobile bit so that wont be a problem anymore.

Comment: @octopusblonde JQM loads pages via ajax, so as long as it's enabled, `#top` means a page with ID top. Disabling ajax for that anchor stops JQM from handling the hash as a page.

Answer (score 0):

One issue I found is in your header. Chrome has an error parsing the meta tag with name="viewport"

It complains that "device-width;" for key "width" is invalid
It also says to use a comma for separating the key-value pairs, not a semicolon.

EDIT: Looks like you should just replace the semicolon with a comma to solve that error. device-width for key width seems to be ok. Source: https://github.com/poole/hyde/issues/11

No clue if that'll fix the broken links though. Really strange to see the fragment identifiers not working. The URL doesn't change at all when you click on one of the menu items. Do you have some sort event listener that would preventDefault on links?

Comment: Ok, I copy pasted the way they have it in the HTML5 boilerplate with the comma.... no change.